# Promise.all() work around for IE 11 with Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, internet-explorer-11, es6-promise

**Background:** I have been tasked to help resolve an issue with the following error:

```
'Promise' is undefined'
```

Which is part of our sessionsmodel.js script:

```
return Promise.all(promises);
```

`promises` is an array of actions that need to happen and if any fail it is rejected.

**Question:** Based on my research IE does not support `Promise` so is there a work around that can be applied to this return value that will accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Yea, there is one solution - Switch browser! IE is dead. It won't get any more updates

Comment: Search for some "promise polyfill" on google

Comment: Unfortunately the end client probably won't go for that answer but I agree with you. lol.

Comment: Will do I had already done some research and came across polyfill I just figured I would also reach out to the SO community and see if there were other options.

Comment: Rewrite the code to use regular callbacks instead.

Comment: ES6 Promise spec was implemented by "good" libraries like Q, When, RSVP, Bluebird, Lie and more... You can use one of them...

Comment: Thanks @sidanmor for your recommendation I will keep those options in mind.

Comment: So I will post it as an answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using Backbone, the promises are probably jQuery promises. You could use [**jQuery `.when` function**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to do the same as `Promise.all`:

```
return $.when.apply($, promises);
```

For most other simple situations where you call functions like `save` and `fetch`, you could avoid promises completely by using the provided callbacks:

```
model.save({
    context: this,
    success: this.onModelSuccess
});
```

There's no need to use another library because **Backbone uses jQuery already (by default)**, unless you don't like [jQuery deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) or that you're using something else in place of jQuery.

Comment: For anyone still supporting IE11, and happen to use jQuery < 3, note that if `promises` holds native promises instead of `$.Deferred` objects, they won't be unwrapped, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51510862/3002584).

Answer (score 1):

ES6 Promise spec was implemented by "good" libraries like [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), [When](https://github.com/cujojs/when), [RSVP](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/), [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html), [Lie](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/lie) and more...

If you want to learn more on Promises, check this link:
[Promises](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use a [polyfill](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise).